# How to Connect JavaScript Functions for Browser/JS Engine Efficiency?

Tags: javascript

I'm far from an expert but have a decent understanding of how to code and use functions, but I am quite ignorant of how the manner in which the various functions are coded together impacts how the browser reads and processes them.  My old JS book states that a script processes once from top to bottom and then waits and listens for some event to trigger the execution of additional code; but that is about as far as the book covers.  I understand that much, but would like to know more concerning how to code for the browser or any JS engine in general in the sense of making it easier for the browser to do whatever it does to construct that interconnected set of functions like some sort of confusing flow chart.

The code I'm working on now, for example, does very little upon processing the script, apart from initializing some variables and opening a database, until the user interacts with the page and then there are numerous `Promise.allSettled` statements that invoke functions that invoke other functions that catch errors that may bring you right back to attempting a subset of that original array of promises. Nothing spectacular, of course, for I'm just an amateur; but, after I got it all working, I stop and think about whether or not there isn't a better way of coding it all to better fit how the browser/JS engine reads and applies it.

The example below is quite peurile, I realize, but it illustrates the kind of information I'm looking for to apply in more complex code sets.

```
parent.addEventListener( 'click', handler, false );

function handler( evt )
 {
   let e = evt.target;
   if ( e.matches( .. ) ) func_1();
   else if ( e.matches( .. ) ) func_2();
   else if ( e.matches( .. ) ) func_3();
   else if ( e.matches( .. ) ) func_4();
   else if ( e.matches( .. ) ) func_5();
 }
```

What are the differences, in terms of how the browser will interpret the code, between:

1. Declaring the functions `func_1, func2, ... func_n` within/local to function `handler`?
2. Declaring the functions `func_1, func2, ... func_n` globally?
3. Declaring the functions `func_1, func2, ... func_n` as properties of function `handler`?
4. Simply including the code of functions `func_1, func2, ... func_n` in the if statement code blocks and not invoking any other functions from within the function `handler`?

Just to be clear, I understand the differences between and uses of local and global functions, and functions that are properties of objects, from where they can be referenced, etcetera. I'm interested in understanding what the browser has to do when function `handler` is invoked, and how I can code to make it most efficient.

A couple articles I was reading over used the term 'overhead' and suggested keeping functions as small as possible to reduce it.  That sounds reasonable, of course, but I'm not at all clear on what that means in real situations in which the handler routes to one of ten functions, each of which invokes two or three others to complete its task.  Does the browser have overhead at each event for only the functions that are ultimately invoked or does it still have the overhead for all of the functions that each function could invoke but then just invokes the path of functions necessary based on the event details and other applicable data?

I'm looking for information similar to how to code C for the compiler but specifically regarding functions in JavaScript. Where can I find answers to these types of questions? I can find much information concerning how to code different kinds of functions but not on how to properly connect them in a manner that is better/best for the browser to use efficiently.

Thank you.

Comment: This will not answer your question but I want to share my two cents. 1) If you do this level of micro managing, you will lose your mind and won't get any work done. There is a big difference between the set of requirements a compiler and a web application has to satisfy. 

2) Javascript is a language where a simple addition is a 17 step algorithm so if you are really worried about efficiency you are using the wrong language. Many examples show that people who wrote the language didn't give damn

More below..

Comment: 3) I believe #2 will be most efficient but the difference will be in-noticeable. Browser will likely run our of heap space, before you notice a performance difference between these approaches

4) Overhead is a very general term. Keep your functions small, data structures clean and short, avoid repetitive, duplicate work, use tail recursion if you can, don't unnecessarily nest stuff, and you will be fine

Comment: @sinanspd Thank you for your response. I feel as though I have been experiencing your first two comments much lately trying to make something closer to a full desktop application in a single web page.  I've been employing #2 in nearly all the code.  Your fourth comment sounds like good advice. Thanks again I appreciate it.